# Maintain multiple versions of same class at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, html-parsing

I collect HTML data and parse it asynchronously.  I have parser class that implements

```
interface IParser { Loan Parse(string html); }
```

With time html changes a little but enough to break parsing and the parser class needs to be updated.

Some data will be parsed at later time when the parser no longer fits the old data format, other times parsing will fail and need to be retried at later time with the same or another parser.

So I need to have all versions of the parser available at the same time so I can retry parsing data from different time. I'm thinking of having

```
class Parser1 : IParser {...}
class Parser2 : Parser1, IParser {...}
class Parser3 : Parser2, IParser {...}
...
```

and find the current latest version with reflection. Is there a known solution or best practice to manage this ?

Comment: as long as you're not talking about a vast amount of classes, I'd avoid reflection and write a factory which you pass the version number. of course it would be possible to enumerate the implementations of the `IParser` interface in the current assembly, and sort them by number descending (if you pad the numeric part, like Parser001...Parser017). how would you control the instantiation - like starting with newest one and falling back through the versions until one works out?

Comment: HTML Is highly flexible since it doesn't need to be compiled. c# classes, however, is a different story. I would suggest not hard-coding the parsing mechanism but build a parser that will load the parsing definitions from a configuration file. This way, you can always add a new segment to the configuration file with the same tag name and different version attribute.